# Providing a unique ID when writing a Linux kernel driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uniqueidentifier

I've written an I2C driver.  The chip can provide a unique ID.

Is there a generic way of providing chip UIDs to userspace?

Or should I just create `/sys/mydriver/uid` and call it a day?

Comment: Why do you need such UID to be visible? What the use case? And second question what is that chip for? Maybe there is already a framework that povides necessary attributes.

Comment: Btw, you mixed **driver** attribute (which is **not** your case, but you mentioned it) with the **device** [instance] attribute.

Comment: @0andriy Sorry for the driver/device confusion.  The device is a custom power management unit and there can be only one.  The chip does GPIO, IIO (raw/scaled voltages) and Unique ID over I2C.

Comment: Is there any similar data sheet or documentation that we can look at to understand that UID function?

Comment: @0andriy Sorry, no, it's an in-house device.  The driver already reads the correct UID value over I2C, I just wanted to see if there was an common place for Unique IDs, other than /sys/mydriver.

Comment: So as I said it all depends on use case. Why user space would need that? What it will do with it? Does kernel has similar interfaces already with user space?